# iOS8 UISearchBar in UIToolbar has no left padding

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

I have a UIViewController class that contains a UITableView.  In the table view header, I have a UIToolbar containing, among other things, a UISearchBar.  In iOS8, when I tap on the search bar to search, the search display controller animates the bar to the top of the screen as expected, but the search bar has no margin on the left hand side.

The most stripped down of the code that reproduces is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [self tableView].frame.size.width, 44.0)];

    if ([toolbar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
        [toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }

    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:toolbar];

    UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] frame]];

    [[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [searchBarView addSubview:[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar]];
    [[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setText:@""];
    UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarView];

    [toolbar setItems:@[searchBarItem]];
}
```

Any help / suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Edit: This works correctly on iOS 6.1 and 7.0/1

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a iOS8 bug.
You can use a temporary solution from [this](https://gist.github.com/scheinem/f579fc01209b033aac91)

Basically, you can create a subclass of UIToolbar.
Then in subclass you just created, add this code to append missing space:

```
#define DEFAULT_APPLE_PADDING 20.0f
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(view.class) hasPrefix:@"UIToolbar"] &&
            [NSStringFromClass(view.class) hasSuffix:@"Button"]) {
            CGRect buttonFrame = view.frame;

            if (buttonFrame.origin.x == 0) {
                buttonFrame.origin.x = DEFAULT_APPLE_PADDING;
            } else if (buttonFrame.origin.x + buttonFrame.size.width == self.bounds.size.width) {
                buttonFrame.origin.x -= DEFAULT_APPLE_PADDING;
            }

            view.frame = buttonFrame;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Answers with references to external links only will become obsolete if those links are broken. Please include some descriptions and codes on how content in your link help answer OP's question.